# How can I have a seperate variable for each instance of an HTML class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple Cricket scoreboard in JavaScript.  I basically have a div, and each time you click it, it cycles between a few different background images.  You can see what I mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/89d5hutn/).

The HTML in example 1 is:

```
<div class = "click"></div>
```

So that works fine, but I used a global variable to count the image cycle, so when I try to add multiple boxes, this happens:

```js
var x = 0;

$('.click').click(function() {
  x++;
  if (x == 4) {
    x = 0;
  }

  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("none")')
      break;
    case 1:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/25qbHoC.png")');
      break;
    case 2:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/9pcneSb.png")');
      break;
    case 3:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/Vfxu8ap.png")');
  }
});
```

```css
.click {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  background-size: 150px 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
```

How can I prevent this from happening and just have multiple of what you saw in the first example?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: But separately: You've realized you need to remember this information per-element. Good! So do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and try to do that. (Hint: There's a jQuery function specifically for doing that.) ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I created an [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qgL0npm/8/). It's similar to the other answers, so I didn't bother posting it.

Comment: A fiddle is great, but unfortunately jsFiddle does go down from time to time, which would have rendered your question unanswerable and useless for future visitors. It's for this reason that SO specifies that all relevant code should be placed in the question with the fiddle as a backup example. In this case I've edited the code in to your question as an executable snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a global counter instead of one per instance of the images. To fix this you could use a `data` attribute to store the counter specific to that image.

Also note that you can make your logic much more succinct by storing the image settings in an array and accessing that instead of a `switch` statement. You can also use the modulo operator to negate the need to reset the counter back to `0`. Try this:

```js
var images = [
  'url("none")',
  'url("https://i.imgur.com/25qbHoC.png")',
  'url("https://i.imgur.com/9pcneSb.png")',
  'url("https://i.imgur.com/Vfxu8ap.png")'
]

$('.click').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var x = $el.data('counter') || 1;
  $el.css('background-image', images[x % 4]).data('counter', ++x);
});
```

```css
.click {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  background-size: 150px 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="click"></div>
```

Comment: What happens when the user clicks more than the max 32bit int?

Comment: @FrankerZ: you mean when the user clicks more than `4,294,967,295` 
 (FFFFFFFF in hex) times? .oO(lol)

Comment: If someone wants to click `9,007,199,254,740,991` times they have earned their exception :)

Comment: It would be cool that someone tries... To tell if there is an issue. I won't.

Comment: That would be a very dedicated QA analyst.

Comment: According to an online tester I found my fastest click rate is 6.9 per second. Let's be generous and call it 7. At that rate you'd only need to constantly click for 40,802,344 years.

Comment: So, you're telling me there's a chance. (am I allowed to use YouTube links? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMRrNY0pxfM)

Comment: You'd have to prepay your ISP bill in advance to be sure the test finishes!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the answer.  Could I ask what exactly `|| 1`means in the third to last line of the JS?

Comment: It's using JS's falsy nature to set the default value of `x`. It's basically saying, set `x` to the value of `data('counter')`, or if that's not defined, set it to `1`

Answer (score 0):

To make each  have its own counter, you can use data attributes, which are bound to the tag in question and easily accessible via jQuery, which your tags specified you are using:

```
<div class="click" data-count="0"></div>
```

I added the data attribute to the HTML above, but the code below will actually dynamically add it, if it doesn't exist, on the first click.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
  //get existing count+1 or 0+1 if it the data-attribute doesn't exist.
  var x       = ($(this).data('count') || 0) + 1;
  //reset back to zero if we've gotten to 4
  x           = x >= 4 ? 0 : x;
  //set our new value back into the data attribute so the next run can
  //increment.
  $(this).data('count',x);

  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("none")')
      break;
    case 1:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/25qbHoC.png")');
      break;
    case 2:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/9pcneSb.png")');
      break;
    case 3:
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.imgur.com/Vfxu8ap.png")');
  }
});
```